# Concatenating hardcoded directory and user-created text file adds root-level paths when it shouldn't

Tags: linux, bash, apache, loops, scripting

I have written a script to allow a restricted user access to deleting files on a production webserver. However, to prevent fat-fingering issues leading to accidental filesystem deletion/problems, I have hard coded the base directory in a variable... But the final result is not properly creating the desired path from hard-coded directory + user paths if they have a * wildcard...

I have an Apache 2.4.6 server that caches web content for a user. They have a jailkit user to SSH into this box. As this is production, they are severely limited in their access, however, I would like to give them the ability to clear specific cache directories on their own terms. In order to prevent this from going horribly wrong, I have hard-coded the base cache directory into a script variable, so that no matter what, the script will only run against that path.

So far, this script works well to iterate through their desired cache clear paths... A user creates a .txt file with a /cachePath defined on each line, and the script will iterate through it and delete those paths. It works just fine for /path and /content/path2/ ... But I cannot for the life of me get it working with wildcards (i.e. /path/*, /content/path2/*). There's probably a sexier way to handle this than what I've done so far (currently have an if | else statement for handling * or /* not included in the script below), but I am getting all kinds of undesired results trying to handle a user-inputted * or /* on a custom path.

```
#!/bin/bash
#For this to work, a user must create a paths.txt file in their jailed home directory, based off the /mnt/var/www/html cache location. Each location (or file) must be on a new line, and start with a / 

    #User-created file with custom cache directories to delete
    file="/usr/jail/paths.txt"

    #Setting this variable to the contents of the user-created cache file
    pathToDelete=$(cat $file)

    #Hard-coded cache directory to try to prevent deleting anything important outside cache directory
    cacheDir="/mnt/var/www/html"

    #Let's delete cache
    if [ -f $file ];then
            echo "Deleting the following cache directories:"
            for paths in $pathToDelete
            do
                    echo $cacheDir"$paths" 
                    #rm command commented out until I get expected echo 
 output
                    #rm -rfv $cacheDir"$paths"
            done
            echo "Cache cleared successfully"
            mv $file "$file.`date +"%m%d%Y%H%M"`"
    else
            echo "Nothing to do"
    fi
```

I've tried double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, tried treating "pathToDelete" as an array, none of it is producing the desired output yet. For example, if paths.txt contains only "*", the result is grabbing all directories under / and adding them to "cacheDir"?

```
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/backup
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/bin
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/boot
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/data
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/dev
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/etc
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/home
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/lib
/mnt/var/www/html/testing/lib64
...
```

If paths.txt is "./*" it's adding files from the location of the script itself:

```
/mnt/var/www/html/testing./cacheClear.sh
/mnt/var/www/html/testing./paths.txt
```

Ultimately, what I'm looking for is this: if /mnt/var/www/html contains the following directories:

```
/content/
/content/path/
/content/path/file1.txt
/content/path/file2.txt
/content/path/subdir/
/path2/
/path2/fileA.txt
/path2/fileB.txt
```

Then a file containing 
`/content/path/*` 
should delete /content/path/file1.txt, file2.txt, and /subdir/, and preserve the /content/path/ directory.

If the paths.txt file contains

```
/content/path
/path2/*
```

Then /content/path directory and subfiles/directories should be deleted, and the files within /path2/ directory will as well... But right now, the script doesn't see the concatenated `$cacheDir` + `$paths` as a real / expected location if it contains a * anywhere in it. Works ok without * symbols.

Comment: try `cd ${cacheDir}` before you load the `pathToDelete` variable - this should ensure wildcard expansion is applied from within the `html` directory

Comment: Hmm, well it seems like it does `cd` into the dir, but then `rm` ends up doing nothing. What I have for that:
```for paths in $pathToDelete
                        do
                                cd ${cacheDir}
                                rm -rfv "$paths"``` and it has deleted nothing at all in that dir.

Comment: modify your script to print the contents of `$paths`, then manually run the same steps as the script is performing ... verify your `cd` is correct (eg, what does `pwd` show), and does the `rm` work or is there another issue?

Comment: Yeah I've done that too... Here's the output of the script with echo for pwd, `$paths`, and `$cacheDir`
```Deleting the following cache directories:
This is cacheDir variable:
/home/cachetest/testing
This is paths:
/dir1/*
This is pwd:
/home/cachetest/testing
This is cacheDir variable:
/home/cachetest/testing
This is paths:
/dir2
This is pwd:
/home/cachetest/testing``` And when it's finished, nothing has been deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a version that works well enough for my purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/usr/jail/paths.txt"
pathToDelete=$(cat $file)
cacheDir="/mnt/var/www/html"

if [ -f $file ]; then
        if [ "$pathToDelete" == "*" ] || [ "$pathToDelete" == "/*" ]; then
                echo "Full Clear"
                rm -rfv /mnt/var/www/html/*
        else
                echo "Deleting the following cache directories:"
                for i in ${pathToDelete};
                do
                        echo ${cacheDir}${i}
                        rm -rfv ${cacheDir}${i}
                done
                echo "Cache cleared successfully"
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code is a working solution:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
file="/usr/jail/paths.txt"
pathToDelete="$(sed 's/^\///' $file)"
cacheDir="/mnt/var/www/html"
if [ -f $file ];then
  echo "Deleting the following cache directories:"
    for paths in "$pathToDelete"
    do
      echo $cacheDir/$paths
      rm -rfv $cacheDir/$paths
    done
    echo "Cache cleared successfully"
else
  echo "Nothing to do"
fi
```

Comment: Yeah that may be a solution, I'd just have to make sure the user knows to not include a lead `/` in the paths to avoid `testing//dir1/test1.txt`. Still doesn't fix the issue where if they only have `*` it appends root-level directories like `/bin, /boot, /dev` but I can handle txt input of `*` or `/*` with an if statement there ..

Comment: I have modified the code so that now it works under any circumstance (including the single `*` as a path). You can write your paths with or without an initial slash (it will be ignored and considered only as a relative path inside `/mnt/var/www/html`)